# PHP - Stop Concurrent User Logins

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication, user-management

I need a method of stopping concurrent logins using PHP/MySQL.

**The current setup**

Currently there are 2 people sharing the same login on a system i have built internally where i work. Due to the nature of the system i dont want them both logging in.

**What I have tried**

Around 10 articles on stackoverflow and googled for as long as i can.

I also attempted adding a "loggedin" field in the user table which upon logging in was set to 1 and upon logging out was set to 0. Then if the same user credentials where used at login, it would fail.

The problem i had was that if the person who was logged in shut down the browser without logging out properly, it wasnt updating the database. Then i get a phone call from that person and i would have to reset the value to 0 in the database.

This isn't feasible going forward as the product is being rolled out to around 20 people internally soon.

**What I need**

What i need is to find a way that when the browser closes a script gets executed to update the database. Alternatively a way of reading every current session on the server, which i could manipulate, or something else.

**Restrictions**

Our hosting providers are awful and subsequently what changes i can make to the server are limited/impossible. The hosting is a shared hosting solution.

Comment: Change the password.  But it won't matter if person x tells person y the new password.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What i need is to find a way that when the browser closes a script gets executed to update the database.

You can't.

Your best solution may be associating the session ID with the user in the database. If the session ID on the user's computer doesn't match the most recent session ID in the database, make them log in and update the db.

Comment: This is probably just about the only way to make sure you are keeping one login per user. On login, store the session with the user in the database. After that, you just verify that the session with the user account matches the session of the user trying to load the page. If it doesn't match, log them out and force a re-login.

Comment: Im sure your both right but i just cant get to grips with what your saying, its not making sense in my head.

Comment: User 1 logs in as 'user' and gets a session ID of 'ABC'. You save 'ABC' into the database in the row for 'user'. User 2 logs in as 'user' and gets a session ID of 'DEF'. You save 'DEF' to the database. The next time user 1 does anything, your script sees that 'ABC' is no longer the right session ID for 'user', and logs them out.

Comment: Right ok that makes sense. But problem with that is that the application is used for creating emails. Now whilst the application does autosave every 5 seconds its still going to annoy who ever is logged in that they've been logged out. And then il get it in the neck. @ceejayoz @Jonathon Kuhn

Comment: The correct response to that should be "stop sharing usernames", then.

Comment: @itsphil - so why don't you just leave it the way it is?

Comment: Whilst i dont doubt that your right in what your saying and il give you the correct answer...im trying to avoid having to rewrite shed loads of code to allow for sharing of emails etc...yes i know something that should have been specced out, but when your boss hurries you to get something out this happens.

Answer (score 3):

perhaps you should flip this around.

the person trying to log in gets a new session, and the new session invalidates any old sessions for the same username (thus logging them out)

this way only one person can be logged in at a time.

Comment: Agreed. This is the ideal way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fool-proof way to do this, by the very nature of HTTP.  But if you can deal with some lag time, there is a solution.

The best you could do is have a JS script hit a "keep-alive" script on your server.  Do this every 30 seconds or so.  If your server hasn't heard from the client within 1 minute, close the session.

Comment: It does if each user only gets one session...  I had assumed he would have set up his account system in that way, but that was probably a bad assumption to make.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "loggedin" field, but adding another field "loggedin_timestamp". Then you check when the user has logged in for the last time.

If it's bigger than session persistence time, you allow him to log in again automatically

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the jquery delay time out session script to auto logout them. The script will call back a php script by which we can change the database session out time stamp. So, i think this link will help you. [Jquery idle time out](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/)