# How to stop concurrent logins from same userid in php

Tags: php, authentication

How we can stop a user to login if he/she is already login in php?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126285/php-stop-concurrent-user-logins?rq=1

Comment: When the users is loged in create a session, then on top of the login page write if(isset($_SESSION['session'])) {echo "You are loged in";}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stop someone from logging if he already logged from the same computer, then you should redirect from the login.php page (for example) if the session/cookie exists.

If you want to avoid multiple loggins from the same accounts (from another computer) then add a row in the users table on the database which will store the session of the user, when the user is logging in you will store his session ID, then you can identify this user with his session ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise session management techniques, which entails storing a session ID in the users cookie so when a request comes to your site with a particular session ID you can check whether the user associated with that session ID is already marked as logged in in your system. [Here's](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/51558-session-handling-in-php/) a reference to get you started...